# how to incorporate a daterangepicker based in angular 6 into a project based in angular 7?

Tags: angular, daterangepicker

I found this module online

[Date range picker based in Angular 6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-daterange-picker)

But the problem is my project is made from angular 7, is there a way to incorporate this thing ? because when I tried to install the peer dependencies according to its manual via

```
npm install @angular/animations@^6.1
npm install @angular/cdk@^6.1
npm install @angular/material@^6.1
```

the project got messed up and become unusable and I had to remove the node_modules and re-install my whole project again

npm install angular-mater

Comment: Last publish 9 months ago ... Not sure you should use a discontinued package. But for questions, like this, provide a [mcve] : `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-daterange-picker) library then it is for angular V6 and below. I don't know if it will work with angular v7 although it should.

Please provide code depicting what you have done or even better if you can create a sample stackblitz example.
For your reference below are two stackblitz example implementing the ngx-mat-daterange picker example.
You can see the example and pinpoint the issue.
Hope it helps.

Link 1: [Stackblitz Example 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-daterangepicker-material-rfvv3o) // I will use this one.It is much better

Link 2: [Stackblitz Example 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-daterangepicker)

Comment: I don't have yet a code for it, I only know how to use a plugin if we are talking about jquery. Am totally new to Angular ..do you have a sample which includes custom ranges like last 7 days ,yesterday, lasst 30 days and etc. ?

Comment: @sasori Look at the two stackblitz example I have mentioned . It is a running angular application with code and when you want to implement it you can copy the code and use it in your application

Comment: thanks for the help. @Ahmed , anyway, I found a nice library to use . it fits in Angular 7 project .   [Date range picker for Angular 7]


  [1]: https://github.com/qqnc/ngx-daterangepicker

Comment: I checked it out too..it's pretty cool ... i am going to use it too if I ever need it..thank you